# Laravel при частом обновлении вылетает ошибка 500/нет таблицы. Laravel on fast page refresh error 500/table not found

Tags: php, laravel

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRZfLJivpcI&feature=youtu.be - видео с проблемой на youtube

Из-за чего это происходит?

```
production.ERROR: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'taxi.users' doesn't exist
```

Выполнял команды:

```
php artisan key:generate
php cache:clear
```

**это не помогает**

Laravel последней версии из коробки.

Запускается на OsPanel PHP7.3.

Такую же проблему наблюдал еще в Laravel 4, но она была не такой частой, и как-правило, я не успевал ее отлавливать.

Я так понял, видео никто не смотрит, и минусует вопрос, считая, что я задал его просто так, и мне лень гуглить. Окей, проясню всё в текстовом формате.

1. Таблица users существует (в двух базах данных, с которыми устанавливается соединение).
2. Код тестового контроллера

> ```
>     public function index()
>     {
>         $users = User::all();
>         dd($users);
>         exit;
>     }
> ```

3. Роут тестового контроллера

> ```
> Route::get('/testError', 'TestController@index')->name('test');
> ```

4. Результат выполнения (не развернутый, если нужно, предоставлю и его), если не обновлять слишком часто:

> ```
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1088 ▼
>   #items: array:2 [▼
>     0 => App\Models\User {#1090 ▶}
>     1 => App\Models\User {#1089 ▶}
>   ]
> }
> ```

5. Если обновлять очень часто, то появляется ошибка 500, `"... AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC ..."`, а также изредка проскакивает, что таблицы users не существует (из нее выводятся данные в тестовом контроллере, для особо невнимательных сделаю еще раз акцент на том, что таблицу видит, если не обновлять страницу очень часто)
6. Регенерация ключей и очистка кеша не помогает.

Comment: А вы искали в Гугле? Там ошибка явно написана и очень четко

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку,  на статью, в которой описано решение данной проблемы? Все, что есть в гугле по этой ошибке, сводится к выполнений команд генерации ключа и очистки кеша, которые, я, разумеется, выполнял

Comment: `php artisan key:generate && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Обновился до Laravel 8, проблема ушла.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/516377)

Comment: Я и есть автор, и это является решением проблемы, описанной в вопросе. Я здесь новичок, поэтому не знаю, как закрыть вопрос. Можете подсказать?

Comment: Я понял, что Вы автор) Вы могли просто обновить свой вопрос, дополнив этой информацией. А так для сообщества вопрос не представляет ценности, потому что не решен, а просто Вы сумели избежать проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

У Вас нет таблицы "users", если у Вас Laravel 6.x +, то выполните следующие команды:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Если версия ниже, то

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы шутите?) Посмотрите видео, сайт полностью функционирует, таблица users есть, и из нее выводятся данные. Вот только если очень часто обновлять страницу, то вылетает ошибка 500, логи кооторой говорят о проблеме с ключами и несуществуеющей таблице в базе данных (отмечу еще раз, таблица есть)

Comment: Изменил описание вопроса, добавил больше информации, дабы прояснить такие неочевидные вещи, как то, что таблица существует, и вопрос я задаю не от нечего делать